# Changing JS effect coded for an ID to a Class

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to us a scrolling text JavaScript that I found on JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sdleihssirhc/AYYQe/3/

I'm not experienced with JavaScript and just starting to learn about jQuery.

The code is using an ID

HTML

`<p id="tweet">These English psychologists, to whom...</p>`

CSS

```
#tweet, #tweet_js { border:1px solid red; width:25em; padding:.5em; }
#tweet_js { overflow:hidden; white-space:nowrap; }
.hiding { text-overflow:ellipsis; }
```

I need #tweet to be a class so I can use it multiple times on the same page.

the JavaScript seems to be using the ID #tweet and creating another ID #tweet_js

JavaScript

```
var tweet = document.getElementById('tweet');
tweet.id = 'tweet_js';
tweet.className = 'hiding';

var slide_timer,
max = tweet.scrollWidth,
slide = function () {
    tweet.scrollLeft += 1;
    if (tweet.scrollLeft < max) {
        slide_timer = setTimeout(slide, 40);
    }
};

tweet.onmouseover = tweet.onmouseout = function (e) {
e = e || window.event;
e = e.type === 'mouseover';
clearTimeout(slide_timer);
tweet.className = e ? '' : 'hiding';
if (e) {
    slide();
} else {
    tweet.scrollLeft = 0;
}
};
```

Can someone please show me how to change the JavaScript so this effect can work with a class (.tweet) instead of the ID (#tweet). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The first line try changing to

```
var tweet =  document.getElementsByClassName('tweet');
```

make sure you have a class called tweet for the html element in question..

```
<p id="tweet" class="tweet">These English psychologists, to whom...</p>
```

Not sure if this will work. good lucks

Comment: I tried changing the first line to what you provided, and added the class to the element, but it didn't work. Thank you very much anyway